# big query SQL - repeatedly/recursively change a row's column in the select statement based on the values in previous row

Tags: sql, recursion, google-bigquery

I have table like below

| customer | date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan 1 2021 | jan 30 2021 |
| 1 | jan 2 2021 | jan 31 2021 |
| 1 | jan 3 2021 | feb 1 2021 |
| 1 | jan 27 2021 | feb 26 2021 |
| 1 | feb 3 2021 | mar 5 2021 |
| 2 | jan 2 2021 | jan 31 2021 |
| 2 | jan 10 2021 | feb 9 2021 |
| 2 | feb 10 2021 | mar 12 2021 |

Now, I wanted to update the value in the 'end date' column of a row based on the values in the previous row 'end date' and the current row 'date'.
Say if the date in current row < end date of the previous row, I wanted to update the end date of the current row = (end date of the previous row).
I Wanted to do this repeated for all the rows (grouped by customer).

I want the output as below. Just need it in the select statement instead of a updating/inserting in a table.

Note - in below as the second row(end date) is updated with the value in the first row (jan 30 2021), now the third row value (jan 3 2021) is evaluated against the updated value in the second row (which is jan 30 2021) but not with the second row value before update (jan 31 2021).

| customer | date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jan 1 2021 | jan 30 2021 |
| 1 | jan 2 2021 | jan 30 2021 [updated because current date < previous end date] |
| 1 | jan 3 2021 | jan 30 2021[updated because current date < previous end date] |
| 1 | jan 27 2021 | jan 30 2021 [updated because current date < previous end date] |
| 1 | feb 3 2021 | mar 5 2021 |
| 2 | jan 2 2021 | jan 31 2021 |
| 2 | jan 10 2021 | jan 31 2021[updated because current date < previous end date] |
| 2 | feb 10 2021 | mar 12 2021 |

Comment: There is one observation, data in bigquery is not ordered by default. You can check the official documentation [ordered values](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause). I think you should clarify that aspect before jumping further into this logic. You can test yourself by creating an empty table and inserting  the values into that table trough bigquery or loading a csv.

Comment: To explain a bit further, if you insert data into a bigquery table by just using scripts or loading from an external source ( csv ) the order will correlate to that operation. If you decide to update or add new values. ie: you decide to add 2 rows to customer 1 sometimes it will appear as the first value and sometimes at the botton.. of your loaded csv data if you dont specify the order.

Comment: @Betjens I am taking care of the order in the previous step of the query. So, the data is ordered  to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should go this way. I use the datasource twice just to get the way its needed to perform the operation without updating or inserting into the table.

**input table**:

```
1|2021-01-01|2021-01-30
1|2021-01-02|2021-01-31 
1|2021-01-03|2021-02-01
1|2021-01-27|2021-02-26
1|2021-02-03|2021-03-05
2|2021-01-02|2021-01-31
2|2021-01-10|2021-02-09
2|2021-02-10|2021-03-12
```

**code**:

```
with num_raw_data as (
    SELECT row_number() over(partition by customer)as num, customer,date_init,date_end  
    FROM `project-id.data-set.table`
), analyzed_data as(
    select r.num,
    r.customer,
    r.date_init,
    r.date_end,
    case when date_init<(select date_end from num_raw_data where num=r.num-1 and customer=r.customer and EXTRACT(month FROM r.date_init)=EXTRACT(month FROM date_init)) then 1 else 0 end validation
    from num_raw_data r 
)
select customer,
date_init,
case when validation !=0 then (select MIN(date_end) from analyzed_data where validation=0 and customer=ad.customer and date_init<ad.date_end) else date_end end as date_end
from analyzed_data ad
order by customer,num
```

**output**:

```
1|2021-01-01|2021-01-30
1|2021-01-02|2021-01-30
1|2021-01-03|2021-01-30 
1|2021-01-27|2021-01-30 
1|2021-02-03|2021-03-05 
2|2021-01-02|2021-01-31
2|2021-01-10|2021-01-31 
2|2021-02-10|2021-03-12
```

Using column `validation` from `analyzed_data` to get to know where I should be looking for changes. I'm not sure if its fast (probably not) but it works for the scenario you bring in your question.

Comment: Thank you. The use of the min(date_End) in the second case statement is a good one, that will solve my issue. Perhaps I need to use join, instead of the case statement and that might be faster. I will need to add one more condition in this to work for my usecase (the extra condition is "date_int<=(ad.date_end+30)". This is because 1. the dateend for the input table is always 30 days after the dateinit.  2. In the output table, I need  "date_end between date_int+1 and date_int+30" )

Comment: So, once you applied those filters it worked for you? Were you able to set that working on your case?

Comment: yes it worked for my usecase once I added some filters and did the join. I used the min(Date_End) from your logic